# Keyboard becomes unresponsive when Mac shuts down automatically

Tags: keyboard, spaces

I need help with my MacBook Air M1. Every time it shuts down after hours of no use, it opens on the native Ventura wallpaper, and the keyboard is unresponsive. However, the mouse works just fine, and I have to restart it manually with the button. Neither the built-in nor the plugged-in keyboards work in this situation.

Additionally, I use my MacBook Air as a desktop with two external 4K monitors connected via a dock and DisplayLink. But it requires me to open it and manually turn it on each time I start it up. Is there any way to avoid doing this every time?

Lastly, every time I start up the MacBook Air, my spaces get rearranged, presumably because it detects a new screen for a second and rearranges them. (I have the option of rearranging spaces turned off, so it's not that).

Can someone please help me solve these issues?

Thank you!

Comment: "it opens on the native Ventura wallpaper... and I have to restart it manually with the button". Can you explain this better?  If it's already started, why do you need to restart it manually. "with the button" -- the keyboard power button, or the mouse button?

Answer (score 1):

From the EtreCheck report you provided:

There have been numerous crashes: mostly some app called Endurance, which also seems to have installed something to "Disable Turbo Boost". As you're on Apple Silicon, I would uninstall this.

It's likely that your unresponsive keyboard is due to a system crash, so that you have to restart with the power button.

You've only got 8Gb of RAM but as can be seen from the report, you've got SO many background processes running. You also have a lot of kernel extensions, which are deprecated. There's also some software with missing components (AdGuard, OpenVPN).

You've disabled security updates. There's no reason to, and it puts you at risk.

I would also get rid of CleanMyMac. At best, it's unnecessary; at worst, it can cause as many problems as it claims to solve. Your Mac has got so much crap installed that it's hardly 'clean', anyway!

Comment: It is also the external keyboard which is not working

Comment: It might be the case that the laptop has some hardware issues. Recently, I had to go to the store, too, because a password that worked was not working (yes, it only didn't work on that device) which required a complete reboot of sorts. Are you able to tell me what I could try in order to prevent the mac from shutting down when it's supposed to sleep (since that seems to be the issue)—it restarts everything and sometimes requires that reboot via a button if the keyboard is unresponsive.

Comment: @Kamil It possibly sounds like your Mac is experiencing a 'kernel panic', e.g. a complete freeze from which it must be hard reset and rebooted. Diagnosing such a problem requires a thorough assessment of all the software you've got installed. That would explain un unresponsive keyboard until you hold down the power key to restart. You could use Etrecheck to produce a report, which could post here, that will contain detailed information about your computer. (Nothing personal, or identifying.) https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html

Comment: I appreciate your help @benwiggy, I ran the report and reviewed everything, and to my eyes, everything looks to be okay, here's the full report on Pastebin though, if someone could take a look: https://pastebin.pl/view/10f77151

Comment: @Kamil See my revised answer. Everything is clearly not ok!

Comment: So enlightening. Wow, yeah, cleanmymacX. I can see why it could cause issues; ill keep it but be careful, as I paid for it, and it is still useful sometimes. I remove all those unnecessary background processes and apps. I didn't care since the Mac never had performance issues anyway; I'm restarting the computer now, per Etre's instructions, with a software update and generating a new report.

Comment: One last thing, how can I fix the crash issues? Any suggestions?
https://pastebin.pl/view/5c999f16

Comment: @Kamil The crashes are likely caused by some combination of all those background processes you've got. Get rid of as many as possible, test, and then only add the ones back you absolutely need, and see if/when the crashes start. As with Jazz: Less is more. All these little utilities that seem useful, just to save you a couple of keystrokes -- if they have bugs, or aren't up-to-date, then they can cause problems.